# Vuetify: v-card fills up entire v-tooltip

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am creating a tooltip that appears when an icon is clicked or hovered on; I am using a v-card inside the tooltip:

```
            <v-tooltip bottom min-width="15%">
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                <v-icon small
                  v-bind="attrs"
                  v-on="on">
                  mdi-information
                </v-icon>
              </template>

              <v-card flat height="100%" width="100%" class="ma-0 pa-0">
                <v-card-text>
                  Tooltip Text is here
                </v-card-text>
              </v-card>
            </v-tooltip>
```

The v-card does not fill the tooltip entirely. How do I make the v-card fill the entire tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be better to use `<v-menu>` tag with **open-on-hover** prop instead of `<v-tooltip>`.

Example:

```
<v-menu
  open-on-hover
  offset-y
  :close-on-content-click="false"
>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
    <v-icon
      small
      v-bind="attrs"
      v-on="on">
      mdi-information
    </v-icon>
  </template>

  <v-card>
    ...your card data
  </v-card>
</v-menu>
```

[Codepen working example](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/gOxKZMm)

Comment: Will be looking into this as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fill your entire tooltip as I mention there cards are not used here it's made on sheet which could be filled with span tag inside span Whatever you want to write you can...

```
  

    <v-tooltip bottom>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-icon color="primary"
              dark
              v-bind="attrs"
              v-on="on" left>
            mdi-information
          </v-icon>
          </template>
          <span>Bottom tooltip</span>
    </v-tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the v-tooltip `content-class="pa-0"`. You need to override the `padding: 5px 16px;` that's on `.v-tooltip__content`. [Reference to Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tooltip/#props-content-class) on why you use content-class instead of class (detached element like v-dialog and v-menu).